# Start tomcat in linux with verbose

Tags: linux, unix, tomcat

When I want to start the tomcat service I write

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat start
```

However it doesnt give any sign what is happening and sometimes it takes time until the service is fully started.

Is there a verbose command for the tomcat start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start another window and type:

```
tail -f /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out
```

or wherever your log is, that will give you an indication what is happening.